# Unable to load the requested class: M_pdf in server (centos)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I developed project in windows system . in this system i am using m_pdf class to generate pdf file. it runs successfully, but i uploaded in server (centos) which returns error ,it says
**Unable to load the requested class: M_pdf**
what mistakes i have done.

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows environment the lower and uppercase characters are equals, but Linux is case-sensitive. Rename the class and the m_pdf class and file to M_pdf.